# In Azure SignalR Service, what is a Concurrent Connection?

Tags: azure-signalr

The pricing for `Azure SignalR Service` is based on `Concurrent Connections`. 
However, I can't find the definition of a *Concurrent* connection.

I have an `ASP.Net Core` MVC Web Application.  I understand that the server application connection to the `Azure SignalR Service` is one connection.  Each client (browser) that connects to my web app is another connection.  But are these considered *concurrent* connections?  Or just open connections sitting there waiting for a message to be sent?

I'm hoping that the count of *concurrent* connections is a count of connections that are actively sending a message.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I figured out that a *Concurrent* connection is any connection to the SignalR Service!

I ran through the quickstart tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core)

And then used the Azure Metric as I connected various clients to the chat room, and this is what I found:
[image: screenshot of connection count]

After starting the app in debug mode, it seems the server immediately uses 5 connections.  Then, as I open the url in various browser tabs, a new Client connection is established.  As expected, the 16th browser tab does not establish a SignalR connection (Because I am on the Free SignalR Service tier, which has a limit of 20 connections.)

Comment: I guess I'll post as a separate question to understand why the server consumes 5 connections?!?

Comment: This is configured in the AddAzureSignalR method and the default server connection value is 5. You can define the server connection in the configuration like:
```services..AddAzureSignalR(azureOptions =>
            {
                azureOptions.ConnectionCount = 1
            });```